# Matching ouput for HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode in NodeJS Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, node.js, base64, urlencode

I am looking at an example in dotnet which looks like the following: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0y8yD.

The output for the `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` method is:

```
Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq-LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo1
```

When I try to complete the same in NodeJS with `encodeURI`, `encodeURIComponent` or any other attempt I get the following:

```
Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq+LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo=
```

As you can see from the above the '-' should be a '+' and the last character part is different.  The hash is created the same and outputs the same buffer.

```
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha256", buf);
  hmac.update("9644873");
  var hash = hmac.digest("base64");
```

How can I get the two to match? One other important note is that this is one use case and I am unsure if there are other chars that do the same.

I am unsure if the dotnet variant is incorrect or the NodeJS version is. However, the comparison will be done on the dotnet side, so I need node to match that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference of the two results is caused by the use of [Base64URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) encoding in the C# code vs. [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4) encoding in node.js.

`Base64URL` and `Base64` are almost identical, but `Base64` encoding uses the characters `+`, `/` and `=`, which have a special meaning in URLs and thus have to be avoided. In `Base64URL` encoding `+` is replaced with `-`, `/`  with `_` and `=` (the padding character on the end)  is either replaced with `%20` or simply omitted.

In your code you're calculating a HMAC-SHA256 hash, so you get a 256 bit result, which can be encoded in 32 bytes. In `Base64`/`Base64URL` every character represents 6 bits, therefore you would need 256/6 = 42,66 => 43 Base64 characters. With 43 characters you would have 2 'lonesome' bits on the end, therefore a padding char (`=`) is added.
The question now is why `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode` adds a `1` as a replacement for the padding char on the end. I didn't find anything in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode?view=netframework-4.8). But you you should keep in mind that it's insignificant anyway.

To to get the same in node.js, you can use the package [base64url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url), or just use simple `replace` statements on the base64 encoded hash.

With base64url package:

```
const base64url = require('base64url');
var hmacB64 = "Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq+LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo="
var hmacB64url = base64url.fromBase64(hmacb64)

console.log(hmacB64url)
```

The result is:

```
Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq-LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo
```

as you can see, this library just omits the padding char.

With `replace`, also replacing the padding `=` with `1`:

```
var hmacB64 = "Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq+LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo="
console.log(hmacb64.replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=+$/m,'1'))
```

The result is:

```
Pn55YBwEH2S2BEM5qlNrq-LMNE8BDdHYwbWKFEHiPZo1
```

I tried the C# code with different data and always got '1' on the end, so to replace `=` with `1` seems to be ok, though it doesn't seem to be conform to the RFC.

The other alternative, if this is an option for you, is to change the C# code. Use normal `base64` encoding plus string replace to get `base64url` output instead of using `HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`

A possible solution for that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354677/7329832)

Comment: Unfortunately, as we will be calling an API which will compare the two values, they would need to match exactly. Is there a way I can 'shoe-horn' if there is padding with base64url to add the number 1 (instead of = which is currently omitted).

Comment: I tried on your dotnefiddle code and changed the data, but always got '1' on the end, so it seems save to replace '=' with '1'.

Comment: Thanks @jps think I'll just go with the replace now I know more about the difference.

Comment: probably the best soultion for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here so I can't comment (need 50 reputation), but I would like to add to @jqs answer that if the string ends with two "=", the replace needs to be done with "2". So my replace looks like:

```js
hmacb64.replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-').replace(/\=\=$/m,'2').replace(/\=$/m,'1')
```